# How to use "please" in an interrogative sentence

Tags: interrogatives

Can you use "please" in the following sentence?

"Could I please send you a letter?"

I always thought you can't use "please" when you ask someone a permission to do.
There are only two types of questions that you can add please, I thought.

Like,

1. Could you please take that book for me? (When you ask someone to do something for you)
2. Could I get another cup of tea, please? (When you want something from someone)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well the thing is that technically in your example sentence you *are* asking permission to do something: send a letter. You could certainly reword it so you're not doing so, like "I'm going to send you a letter." but phrasing actions being taken as requests is usually done out of politeness.

Comment: Your examples 1. and 2. are interrogatives, but they are not questions; they are directives (specifically, polite requests). You are not asking for answers; in 1. you are asking someone to take some book for you, and in 2. you are asking for another cup of tea. Same with examples like: "Could you please open the door?"; "Could you pass the salt please?"

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you should always use "please" when you ask someone a permission a favor or something else.

So in your question : "Could I please send you a letter ?" as it requests an authorization from the recipient you may put here your *please*.

(However, I'd start with *may* instead of *could*, execept if your question is following ou implying a previous condition...)